# Using %%=ContentBlockbyId("")=%% as Variable Text in Paragraph

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I have a ContentBlockbyId that I need to use to extrapolate the first name, because the data of this field includes full name, just first name, or no name at all. I've worked out the logic that is behind this content block and I'm happy to say this works:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyId("63")=%%
```

However, the issue is that it inserts a line break before and after the code. So that if I wanted to write:

```
I'll see you later, %%=ContentBlockbyId("63")=%%.
```

It would come out as:

```
I'll see you later, 
Shmuel
.
```

Is there anything I can do to remove the `<br>` before and after this so it renders:

```
I'll see you later, Shmuel.
```

Many thanks.

-Shmuel

Comment: are you using a code snippet content block?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an HTML/text block. And ideally, I would like to leave it with just the extrapolated `first name` as this will give me the most freedom to insert it naturally into the body of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a '[Code Snippet](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_code_snippet.htm&type=5)' Content block and not an '[HTML](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_add_html_content.htm&type=5)' block

> Code snippets behave like content blocks but are different because they do not include an extra HTML table that wraps the content.